# Error while using Mantis

Tags: mantis

I want to upload my bug report on mantis that i created on my server machine while I am accessing it from my developing machine I got the following error:

```
APPLICATION ERROR #400
Database connection failed. Error received from database was #1049: Unknown database 'bugtracker'.

Please use the "Back" button in your web browser to return to the previous page. There you can correct whatever problems were identified in this error or select another action. You can also click an option from the menu bar to go directly to a new section.
```

Anyone have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Such error Occurs the go to your `phpmyadmin` page and create a database name `bugtracker` and create all the related table that are being used by mantis.